# After the Jenkins build is successful, it is showing 'No tests to run.' for cucumber automation

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber

I have configured my cucumber web automation with Jenkins, though the build is successful it's showing below error

[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile[m [1m(default-testCompile)[m @ [36mBDDSeleniumFramework[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] **No sources to compile**
[[1;34mINFO[m]
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m--- [0;32mmaven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test[m [1m(default-test)[m @ [36mBDDSeleniumFramework[0;1m ---[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] **No tests to run**.
[[1;34mINFO[m]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>abc.com</groupId>
<artifactId>BDDSeleniumFramework</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<name>BDDSeleniumFramework</name>
<description>BDD-Selenium-Java-Automation-Framework</description>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your test framework is TestNg then you need to add the surefire plugin to your pom.

Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/qmetry/cucumber-maven-example) and update your POM accordingly.